# Passenger error: Could not spawn process for application /home/user/app/current

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, passenger

I'm setting up a Rails app using Nginx and Passenger on Digital Ocean, but I'm getting an error when visiting the IP address.

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.

**Error Log:**
/var/log/nginx/error.log

```
  Could not spawn process for application 
    /home/<user>/<app>/current: An error occurred while starting up the preloader.
  Error ID: 1bb1fce1
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-vZPTxi.html
  Message from application: Unable to autoload constant
    API::Mobile::V1::BaseApiController, expected
     /home/<user>/<app>/releases/20170121053748/app/controllers/api/mobile/v1/base_api_controller.rb 
    to define it (LoadError)
```

If I navigate to the directory being referenced in the error, `~/<app>/releases/20170121172857/app/controllers/api/mobile/v1`, the error relates to the line,

```
class Api::Mobile::V1::BaseApiController < ApplicationController
```

So I'm wondering if there is something wrong with `ApplicationController`? (though it works locally)

*There is more information in a `/tmp/passenger-error...html` file but it was very verbose so I didn't know what to include from it.

**/sites-available/default:**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

        server_name 127.0.0.1;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env production;

        root /home/<user>/<app>/current/public;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root html;
        }
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

**nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}
http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; 
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        include /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

I've seen similar questions on SO but the answers weren't able to help so far.

Is there a common solution to this?